# Is there a single-letter neo-Riemannian transformation between F and Cm?

Tags: neo-riemannian-theory

In [Is there anything special about A♭ in a Tonnetz?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124761/21766), the main diagram makes very clear that there is one adjacent move on the *Tonnetz* that, surprisingly, doesn't have a single-letter transformation associated with it. Here is the diagram:

[image]

On the left side of the diagram, we clearly see that adjacent triangles that share two pitches (i.e., a side) can be understood as P, L, or R. Immediately above we see that, when two triangles share a single node, they can be understood as N or S.

But what about the third option, the PRL transformation that toggles between, e.g., FM and Cm? It seems odd that, in a theory so focused on smooth voice leading, a chord change that shares a common tone would not have a dedicated transformation. Is there a single-letter transformation for this switch?

Comment: ...and if not, why?

Comment: @Aaron my guess is that it has something to do with the tritone between the thirds of the two chords (e.g. A and E flat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In David Kopp's book *Chromatic Transformations in Nineteenth-Century Music*, he does introduce a single-letter transformation that could address this issue.

In Chapter 7 (see specifically pp. 170ff), Kopp introduces the F transformation. F stands for "fifth-change operation," and it connects two triads with different modes related by descending perfect fifth.

Beginning with a C-major triad as stated in the question, an F transformation changes the mode from major to minor and down a perfect fifth to F minor.

But there is a caveat—and a pretty big one in my view. The transformations cited in the question (P, L, R, S, N, and H) are *involutions*, meaning that applying the same transformation to the resulting triad returns you to the original triad. In other words, applying the P transformation to C major takes you to C minor, and applying that same P to C minor takes you right back to C major.

The F transformation, however, is not an involution, because applying F again to the resulting F-major triad from earlier takes us not back to C minor but instead to B♭ minor (recall that the definition of F connects two triads related *by descending perfect fifth*). However, Kopp does address this by creating the F<sup>-1</sup> transformation, which would move by *ascending* fifth to get us back to C minor.

Perhaps this is one reason why—in addition to phoog's great comment that the chordal thirds are a tritone apart—this transformation is simply not mentioned in the same breath as the other six. Nevertheless, for the sake of completeness, I think it's worth having a single-letter transformation—and one that's an involution—for this system. The only question is what to call it...